# Change pitch of Youtube videos

Tags: windows, gratis, youtube

There are nice videos out there on Youtube, but some of them are hard to listen to, because they fall into a frequency region where the tone sounds slightly stressed. An example of such a video is the Clean Code video [Core Design Principles for Software Developers by Venkat Subramaniam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llGgO74uXMI), which I probably want to lower by 3 or 4 semitones.

So I'm looking for

- a free (gratis)
- browser extension (any browser) or other software
- for Windows
- that can change the pitch of the voice, i.e. lower the frequency without changing the speed.

I don't want to download and re-encode the video. It should happen on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is really nifty, it can also slow down and loop Youtube vids:
[Transpose - Pitch - Loop for videos](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/transpose-pitch-loop-for/ioimlbgefgadofblnajllknopjboejda)

[image: Plugin screenshot]

- it's free
- it's a browser extension for Chrome
- it works on Windows
- you can transpose (semitones) and change the pitch (Hertz) and even tempo

Answer (score 1):

There's a Chrome extension you could try: Pitch shifter - HTML5 Video audio FX

> "Pitch shift the audio in HTML5 videos on any webpage, e.g., YouTube"

[Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pitch-shifter-html5-video/mpmkclglcbkjchakihfpblainfncennj?hl=en-GB)